# PackageNotFoundError: Package not found: 'conda' Package 'conda' is not installed in C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39

Tags: anaconda, conda

my problem started when I tried to use `conda create -n nam python3` and got `conda.exceptions.CondaRuntimeError:`

The following packages will be downloaded:

```
package                    |            build
---------------------------|-----------------
vs2015_runtime-14.0.25420  |                0         2.0 MB
vc-14                      |                0          703 B
python-3.6.2               |                0        31.5 MB
certifi-2016.2.28          |           py36_0         214 KB
wheel-0.29.0               |           py36_0         129 KB
wincertstore-0.2           |           py36_0          14 KB
setuptools-36.4.0          |           py36_1         534 KB
pip-9.0.1                  |           py36_1         1.7 MB
------------------------------------------------------------
                                       Total:        36.0 MB
```

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

```
certifi:        2016.2.28-py36_0
pip:            9.0.1-py36_1
python:         3.6.2-0
setuptools:     36.4.0-py36_1
vc:             14-0
vs2015_runtime: 14.0.25420-0
wheel:          0.29.0-py36_0
wincertstore:   0.2-py36_0
```

Proceed ([y]/n)?

Fetching packages ...
vs2015_runtime 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   3.63 MB/s
vc-14-0.tar.bz 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00 140.66 kB/s
python-3.6.2-0 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:05   5.56 MB/s
certifi-2016.2 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   1.18 MB/s
wheel-0.29.0-p 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   1.02 MB/s
wincertstore-0 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   4.84 MB/s
setuptools-36. 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   1.64 MB/s
pip-9.0.1-py36 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:01   1.68 MB/s
Extracting packages ...
[      COMPLETE      ]|##################################################| 100%
Linking packages ...
An unexpected error has occurred.                                        |   0%
Please consider posting the following information to the
conda GitHub issue tracker at:

```
https://github.com/conda/conda/issues
```

Current conda install:

```
           platform : win-64
      conda version : 4.2.7
   conda is private : False
  conda-env version : 4.2.7
conda-build version : not installed
     python version : 3.9.12.final.0
   requests version : 2.28.1
   root environment : C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39  (writable)
default environment : C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39
   envs directories : C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\envs
      package cache : C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\pkgs
       channel URLs : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64/
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch/
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64/
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch/
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/win-64/
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/noarch/
        config file : None
       offline mode : False
```

`$ C:\Users\user\miniconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py create -n nam python`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\conda\install.py", line 201, in yield_lines
    with open(path) as fh:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\pkgs\\vs2015_runtime-14.0.25420-0\\info\\has_prefix'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\conda\install.py", line 209, in yield_lines
    raise StopIteration
StopIteration

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\install.py", line 405, in install
    execute_actions(actions, index, verbose=not context.quiet)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\conda\plan.py", line 643, in execute_actions
    inst.execute_instructions(plan, index, verbose)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\conda\instructions.py", line 134, in execute_instructions
    cmd(state, arg)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\conda\instructions.py", line 78, in LINK_CMD
    link(state['prefix'], dist, lt, index=state['index'])
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\conda\install.py", line 943, in link
    has_prefix_files = read_has_prefix(join(info_dir, 'has_prefix'))
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\conda\install.py", line 248, in read_has_prefix
    return {pr.filepath: (pr.placeholder, pr.filemode) for pr in parsed_lines}
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\conda\install.py", line 248, in <dictcomp>
    return {pr.filepath: (pr.placeholder, pr.filemode) for pr in parsed_lines}
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\conda\install.py", line 247, in <genexpr>
    parsed_lines = (parse_line(line) for line in yield_lines(path))
RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 472, in conda_exception_handler
    return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 144, in _main
    exit_code = args.func(args, p)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_create.py", line 68, in execute
    install(args, parser, 'create')
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\install.py", line 420, in install
    raise CondaRuntimeError('RuntimeError: %s' % e)
conda.exceptions.CondaRuntimeError: Runtime error: RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration
```

my version is conda 4.2 and

I discovered that it's no longer supported, so I used conda update conda and got
PackageNotFoundError: Package not found: 'conda' Package 'conda' is not installed in C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39
, tried to reinstall anaconda and still got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

"C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39"

has nothing to do with **Anaconda**. This the path where standard Python from python.org is installed. Why didn't you mention the 2 Python installations?

Anyhow, before you can use Anaconda you have **activate** it, preferably using the **Anaconda prompt**. Only then can you update conda.

And do yourself a favour: Either learn some conda basics from https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html
or remove it from your system.

Comment: what do you mean by 2 Python installations? there is only python 3.9 on my machine.
and what is wrong with C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39? it was the default path when I installed it?
lastly, I have already seen  https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html and it did not help

Comment: and by the way I am using Anaconda prompt

Comment: when I try to activate anaconda, I got conda runtimeerror as I showed at the beginning